# What is the post install procedure to run c++ programs in cygwin on windows..?

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

I have installed cygwin on windows xp.

On command prompt i type `cygcheck -c cygwin` it give the version of cygwin and says status ok.

but when i type `gcc --version` it give 'gcc command not found'.

What error i am making.
Or is there anything  post install procedure after installing cygwin..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `PATH` environment variable to include the path where `gcc` lives. You may also need other environment variables - see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) - for example environment variables for include path etc.

Comment: gcc/g++ is not present in c:\cygwin\bin.. How to retreive these.. and i have completely installed the cygwin..

Comment: gcc is nothing to do with cygwin. Run cygwin. type `env | grep PATH`. Check the `PATH` variable to ensure that the location of gcc is in it.

Comment: i am getting no gcc present in the path.. What should i do now..?

Comment: Go to the control panel (Control Panel -> System and Maintenance) and update the environment variable PATH by appending the directory for the gcc program.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've updated the PATH env. variable to include "c:\cygwin\bin" (or where ever you've your cygwin binary files installed)

Comment: its done.. thats why i am getting status ok on command cygcheck.. But unfortunately not with command gcc.. However i have completely installed cygwin..

Comment: Is gcc.exe present in your "c:\cygwin\bin" ?

Comment: Maybe it's named with some prefix. like- `xyy-mingw32-gcc.exe` You'd have to make a symbolic link with name gcc

Comment: there is an only file with gcc named : cyggcc_s-1.dll.. and its a dll file not a exe file..

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side make sure you really ticked in the "**GCC for Cygwin 32bit toolchain (C++)**" in the setup.

If you have done this then you should have gcc in your bin directory but you need to create a link and also add it to your path.

To create a link (so that you can use just 'gcc' in short) go to the bin directory and create the link as below:

```
ln -s i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe gcc
```

This will create a symbolic link gcc that points to the real executable ln -s i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe gcc. When this is set up you still need to add the bin directory to your path to be able to invoke gcc anywhere.